# Ng-repeat for images, but firs image is in different div class

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to show product images with ng-repeat, but the problem is that 1 image is in different div. Let me show my code and explain trough what is happening.

This is the response from API which provides me product details and images

```
[{"id_product":"1000","name":"Nikolaus Mount","description":"Ullam labore quibusdam itaque accusamus non ad. Quia architecto voluptates eius. Sed debitis in esse aliquid enim et. Accusamus eos ad distinctio et dolorem.","date_c":"2016-01-08 01:50:45","alias":"nikolaus-mount","images":"[
{\"thumbImage\":\"http:\\\/\\\/lorempixel.com\\\/250\\\/150\\\/?71031\",\"image\":\"http:\\\/\\\/lorempixel.com\\\/1024\\\/768\\\/?38988\",\"position\":0},
{\"thumbImage\":\"http:\\\/\\\/lorempixel.com\\\/250\\\/150\\\/?80440\",\"image\":\"http:\\\/\\\/lorempixel.com\\\/1024\\\/768\\\/?66785\",\"position\":1},
{\"thumbImage\":\"http:\\\/\\\/lorempixel.com\\\/250\\\/150\\\/?64090\",\"image\":\"http:\\\/\\\/lorempixel.com\\\/1024\\\/768\\\/?86379\",\"position\":2},
{\"thumbImage\":\"http:\\\/\\\/lorempixel.com\\\/250\\\/150\\\/?23739\",\"image\":\"http:\\\/\\\/lorempixel.com\\\/1024\\\/768\\\/?25077\",\"position\":3},
{\"thumbImage\":\"http:\\\/\\\/lorempixel.com\\\/250\\\/150\\\/?86200\",\"image\":\"http:\\\/\\\/lorempixel.com\\\/1024\\\/768\\\/?48215\",\"position\":4}]","catAlias":"car-parts","parAlias":"cars-and-bikes"}
]
```

And this is the HTML which renders images

```
<!-- Product Image & Available Colors -->
   <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="product-image-large">
         <a href="{{product[0].images[0].image}}" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="{{product[0].name}}">
         <img src="{{product[0].images[0].image}}" alt="{{product[0].name}}">
         </a>
   </div>
   <div class="colors" ng-repeat="i in product[0].images">
      <a href="{{i.image}}" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="{{product[0].name}}" >
      <img src="{{i.thumbImage}}" alt="{{product[0].name}}" style="float:left; width: 20%;">
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End Product Image & Available Colors -->
```

So the problem is that i print first available image as large, then i have to repeat all 5 images in ng-repeat. I don't wan't to repeat same image as is in large.
I wan't to achieve that i could use ng-repeat only once, firs image must be printed inside  `<div class="product-image-large">` and all next images must be printed in `<div class="colors"><!-- image data --></div>`

I hope you understand me. If you need any additional explanations or code, let me know and i will provide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tweak the `ng-repeat` so that the first image won't be in there:

```
<div class="colors" 
     ng-repeat="i in product[0].images"
     ng-if="!$first"> <!-- this will exclude the first item from the DOM -->
    ..
</div>
```

As @HackedByChinese mentioned, [here is the source](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) where you can check the variables that are leveraged by the `ng-repeat` directive.

---

If the elements (DOM tree) is exactly the same (as in your case), you can just add a class as @Mutmatt mentioned:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'product-image-large': $first, 'colors product-image-small': !$first }" 
     ng-repeat="i in product[0].images">
    ..
</div>
```

and your css:

```
.product-image-large img {
    /* a height larger than normal */
}

.product-image-small img {
    float:left; 
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: I would explain the several "magic" variables that ng-repeat provides to help with this sort of thing: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: That was fast. Good job! I didn't know for $first option.

Comment: you could also use `data-ng-class="'special-first-class': $first, 'other-div-class': !$first"` to just add a class instead of a full div